# How to read open office excel sheet in java and display in gridview

Tags: java, excel

I am very new to java so excuse me if I am asking anything wrong.

I need to develop a web application which reads open office excel sheet. 
The excel sheet has 16 columns and I need to read the data in all the 16 columns and then insert it into the database.

I should also display that data in a grid view.

How can I accomplish these tasks using Java?

Comment: You can start here: http://www.openoffice.org/api/ and come up with some code. Then we would be able to help. Open office has it's own API. And when you say "gridview", do you mean a web application or a GUI with a grid? Be specific on your questions. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache POI library for reading office excel file.
For more information about this library, you can view at here: `https://poi.apache.org/`
After insert data into the database, you can easily display them on screen by select from the database.